# Access .aspx page properties/variable from separate .cs file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Maybe a stupid question. C# 6.0 allows for string replacement using this syntax: $"string content {foo} {bar}". I would like to imitate this behavior in a class I've written for strings passed to it by default. The problem is that I am not sure how to access the public properties/variables. I am not sure if there is a way to access the properties using reflection or by passing this or this.Page to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}

object UID = GetPropValue(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler, "UID");
```